# How do I compare two cells, and copy a value from a third cell if they're the same?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to compare two columns from two different worksheets. In this case, I have a cell 
at B2 in sheet 1, and if the description of this cell is the same as the description of any cell in sheet 2, the cell should display the content of a cell in sheet 1 column G.

Comment: Please don't shout. We can hear you when you speak normally. Also, your question is unclear and is likely to be closed as such soon. You might want to edit it and clarify.

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question (the edit should be visible to you in a couple minutes.) If that's not quite what you meant, you should be able to edit your question further. Try to explain further, and maybe add a screenshot (a picture is worth a thousand words!) or a step-by-step description of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is unclear, but if I understand what you are saying, you will want something that looks similar to this `=IF(logicTest,"valueiftrue","valueiffalse")`  So in your case something like:

`=IF($B$2=G#,=ROWcolumn,"false")`

The way that works is `IF` compares the values and then displays an output if true or another as false.

The "$" means if you copy the function down, it will stay in that specific cell for the comparison.  The =ROWcolumn should be pointed to your cell you want the contents of if the function is true in $1.  "False" is just the value spit out if $1 is false (you could, of course, just do "" for it to be blank).

If you make your question clear with examples, I could target it more - but that should get you off to a start.